# Url manager one path correct, all the others incorrect

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

I have had trouble with this for a long time, and it's getting really annoying. I tried so many ways I'm to the point of really not knowing what to do. This is the only one that would redirect but the problem is I cannot access all the other urls.

this `'<item:.*>'=>'shop/product/view',` redirects to the something like `.com/Whatever+Name?id=89` the id at the end I can't get rid of it. But what's even more annoying is that when I click on all other modules, controllers, I cannot get to them, it's always not found. Even when I tried to replicate something similar like `'<name:.*>'=>'user/profile/view',` I get page not found.

in my urlmanager I have this:

```
'<action:(about|contact|index)>' => 'site/<action>',
'site/category/<id:\d+>'=>array('site/category', 'caseSensitive'=>false),     
'<item:.*>'=>'shop/product/view', //<--this causes problems                 '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<module>/<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Comment: Of course, that will cause you a problem. Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve? Can you give examples of the URL that route entry should match? That means it will match everything

Comment: what do you mean of course? So, `'<item:.*>'=>'shop/product/view',` gets me to the correct page, but if i go any other page it's page not found. Example: if I go to a user module page, or non module (site view) I get page not found, ie: site.com/user/profile/john or site.com/index.php. I'm trying to go to those pages, while having this`'<item:.*>'=>'shop/product/view',` to work

Comment: That ".*" thing will match everything, and will cause a problem if you have other url's below it. Try to put that `<item:.*>` at the end of the list.

Comment: that doesn't work.. then the default `<module><controller><action>` will just override that one.